# Strange Null Reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nullreferenceexception

I get very strange Null Reference as follow in my screen shot:
I do a lot google search for the same case, but cannot see the same issue like this.
Could you please show me some case
Thanks
[image: Strange Null Refference]

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks bosses all
I find out why. 
My issue is null reference of nearly the end of code, not that place.
But I wonder why VS give the error message right there, instead give error message at "expressList" as in my image.
So, another case, I will careful with the other place of code rather than the place VS point to.
Thanks alls
[image]